# Css clip image then resize

Tags: css, image, resize, clip

I got a large image containing different elements for hovering changes. 
the image is quite large so I'd like to clip part of the image and then resize.

```
img {
  clip: rect(0px, 1124px, 186px, 38px);
  width:500px;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
}
```

However, the showed image in the end result is just a small version of the image cutted off at the 1124px bound. (which it doesn't even make) because i set it to 500 px. 
But what I'd like is to have is only the clipped part of the image resized to 500px in width.

what's the best solution?

Explained with visuals at:
https://jsfiddle.net/0m939vmn/

Comment: Can you post a proper code with the sample html you're working on?

Comment: @HarshitDamani updated with jsfiddle

Comment: <br> <img> optional coordinates

Answer (score 0):

today, you can use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) to achieve this, `position` is then optionnal :

```css
img {
  object-fit: none;
  /* will not be resized */
  object-position: 0 0;
  /* clip to your coordonates*/
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

img+img {
  object-fit: none;
  /* will not be resized */
  object-position: 0 -1050px;
  /* clip to your coordonates*/
}

img+img+img {
  object-fit: none;
  /* will not be resized */
  object-position: -1050px -1050px;
  /* clip to your coordonates*/
}

img+img+img+img {
  object-fit: none;
  /* will not be resized */
  object-position: -1050px 0;
  /* clip to your coordonates*/
}
img+img+img+img+img {
  object-fit: none;
  /* will not be resized */
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  /* clip to your coordonates*/
}
```

```html
the following image has width and height of 2000px.<br /> I'd like to have the red square only at a width and height of 500px.
<br />
<br />

<img src='https://picsum.photos/id/20/2000/2000' />
<img src='https://picsum.photos/id/20/2000/2000' />
<img src='https://picsum.photos/id/20/2000/2000' />
<img src='https://picsum.photos/id/20/2000/2000' />
<img src='https://picsum.photos/id/20/2000/2000' />
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

> The `object-fit` CSS property specifies how a replaced element, such as an `<img>` or `<video>`, should be resized to fit its container.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

> The `object-position` CSS property determines the alignment of the selected element inside its box.

---

to clip and **also** resize, beside the clip() you will need to use background-position and background-size loosing the img tag.  or resize & inbricate img within a div and overflow as the most rustic method, i do not post example since i believe you can or have already figured these out..

Comment: @VXp lol, that's what it is about .... it is a copy/paste of the fiddle's op and nowhere doctype used is told. However it won't hurt, browsers are smart enough to correct those armless typos.

Comment: I'm unable to see the images. Perhaps they're no longer available. Would you have the time to update the images?

Comment: @Nae you may use any image you like. what matters is the size it is supposed to be for the test : 2000x2000 pixels being sliced at 500x500 pixels. nowdays object-fit is fine :) **post updated**